# Is openssl AES limited to 256 bits?

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

I am using openssl APIs for AES in my code. What I noticed that AES APIs do not go above 256 bits. I am just curious if this is a limitation within openssl code or if 512 bits with AES is just an overkill.

Comment: Why would you want more? 256 bit AES is already pretty overkillish.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Defense against post-quantum computers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia says ([in the footnote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#cite_note-keysize-0)):

> Key sizes of 128, 160, 192, 224, and 256 bits are supported by the Rijndael algorithm, but only the 128, 192, and 256-bit key sizes are specified in the AES standard.

The Rijndael algorithm seems to work only for a maximum size of `256` bits.

Comment: In "Design of Rijndael" (which is the official specification of Rijndael in book form) it was mentioned that it would be possible to extend the design of the algorithm to larger key sizes, but they didn't see any need for this.

Answer (score 2):

It's already doubtful if AES256 offers any practical advantage over AES128. So AES512 is certainly overkill.

Bruteforce on AES128 is already infeasible. So the danger for AES is crypto analysis. And it's not certain that AES 256 is any stronger than AES128 regarding crypto analysis.

Comment: It depends on how you define crypto analysis. If you face an adversary with a huge storage capacity, and you yourself are generating very large quantities of cipher text, you might want to consider AES 192 or AES 256, just to get a security strength of _at least_ 128 bits.

Comment: I guess it is lack of my understanding. Obviously, the more bits you use in encryption, the more number of combinations a hacker would have to try to break it. I see SSL certificates for 1024 bits and 2048 bits that are commonly used on websites. Are these all overkill? Thank you.

Comment: @Peter Those are talking about RSA keybits. RSA needs a lot more bits. A 2048 bit RSA key is only about as secure as a 128 bit key for blockciphers like AES. RSA is asymmetric encryption, AES a symmetric blockcipher.